# How to search in AppStore for games that have rating from 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: google-search

As you can see on the image below (this is what google shows for a games search):

[image]

if I look for games that have rating from 3.5 to 4.0 you will be able to find them with the following search line:

`site:https://itunes.apple.com/us/app game rating:  3.5..4.2`

as it will look for apps that games "game" and "rating: " in it. And according to [this article](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en) when you look for a range you could use `..`. But look what I see when I search with the range:

[image]

Of course, it is pretty clear that there are tons of games with this criteria. What is the right way to search for them?

Answer (score 1):

According to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28782837/1595451) to [Is it possible to search by microdata/structured data in a standard Google search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782530/is-it-possible-to-search-by-microdata-structured-data-in-a-standard-google-searc) Google Search doesn't support to search by microdata/structured data.

It's worth to note that `rating:` is not listed as a Google Search operator on [Refine web searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en).

An alternative is to create a [Custom Search Engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) with [Filtering and Sorting Search Results](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search)